# how to scaffold-dbcontext to different folders?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2017

We can run the following command that will create the context and models in the project:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=somedatasource.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables PrdSalesRegion -Context SalesRegionContext
```

**How do we specify different output folders for context and tables?**

When I attempt to do this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=somedatasource.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables Models/PrdSalesRegion -Context Context/SalesRegionContext
```

Note, that the only change is:

```
-Tables Models/PrdSalesRegion -Context Context/SalesRegionContext
```

Then I get this output:

> The context class name passed in, Context/SalesRegionContext, is not a
>   valid C# identifier.

**How do we specify different output folders for context and tables?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the flag `-o <DIR>`. You could also use `-f` flag to override existing files while updating existing models with new fields.

The full command could be:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=127.0.0.1;Database=dbname;Username=postgres;Password=test12345"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Entities -f
```

Hope this helps